# Close responsive menu “on click” JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, menu

I need a javascript script to close the menu after clicking on a link.

My html code:

```
<nav>
  <input type="checkbox" id="check">
  <label for="check" class="checkbtn">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </label>
  <label class="logo"><a href="#">My logo</a></label>
  <ul>
        <li><a class="js-scroll-trigger" href="link.html">link</a></li>
        <li><a class="js-scroll-trigger" href="link2.html">link2</a></li>
        <li><a class="js-scroll-trigger" href="link3.html">link3</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

And css: https://www.codepile.net/pile/8nDgZrmE

I don't know how to write a script to hide the menu after clicking the link. I tried my strength, but I dont know how to use javascript.

Thanks a lot for help.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving display: none in click event listener.

```
document.querySelector("ul").addEventListner('click', (event) => {
    if (event.target.closest('li')) {
        document.querySelector("ul").style.display = 'none';
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a simple code for copy paste. I dont know if it is what you want to do but it hides the list on click.

```
<script>
    function toggle() {
        let menu = document.getElementById("menu")
        if (menu.style.display === "none") {
            menu.style.display = "block";
        } else {
            menu.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
</script>
<nav>
  <input type="checkbox" id="check">
  <label for="check" class="checkbtn">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </label>
  <label class="logo" onclick="toggle()"><a href="#">My logo</a></label>
  <ul id="menu">
        <li><a class="js-scroll-trigger" href="link.html" >link</a></li>
        <li><a class="js-scroll-trigger" href="link2.html">link2</a></li>
        <li><a class="js-scroll-trigger" href="link3.html">link3</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simply uncheck the menu button, like this you can control the animation with css like when you open it.

You can try it running the code:

```js
document.querySelector("ul").addEventListener('click', () => { document.querySelector("input#check").checked = false; })
```

```css
nav{
    top: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    height: 80px;
    width: 100%;
}
label.logo{
    color: #B4886B;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 80px;
    padding: 0px 25px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul{
  float: right;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
nav ul li{
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 80px;
  margin: 0 5px;
}
nav ul li a{
  color: black;
  font-size: 17px;
  padding: 0px 13px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

nav a {
  color: #000;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 0.15em;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 0px;
  position: relative;
}
nav a:after {    
  background: repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
  bottom: 0;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 2px;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  background: #000;
  transition: width 0.3s ease 0s, left 0.3s ease 0s;
  width: 0;
}
nav a:hover:after { 
  width: 100%; 
  left: 0; 
}



.checkbtn{
  font-size: 16px;
  color: black;
  float: right;
  line-height: 80px;
  margin-right: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
  z-index: 100;
}
#check{
  display: none;
}
@media (max-width: 952px){
  label.logo{
    font-size: 16px;
    padding-left: 20px;
  }
      
  nav ul li a{
    font-size: 16px;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 858px){
  .checkbtn{
    display: block;
  }
  ul{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    top: 80px;
    left: -100%;
    text-align: center;
    transition: all .5s;
  }
  nav ul li{
    display: block;
    margin: 50px 0;
    line-height: 30px;
  }
  nav ul li a{
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  a:hover,a.active{
    background: none;
    /*color: white;*/
  }
  #check:checked ~ ul{
    left: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous"/>

<nav>
  <input type="checkbox" id="check"/>
  <label for="check" class="checkbtn">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </label>
  <label class="logo"><a href="#">My logo</a></label>
  <ul>
        <li><a class="js-scroll-trigger" href="#">link</a></li>
        <li><a class="js-scroll-trigger" href="#">link2</a></li>
        <li><a class="js-scroll-trigger" href="#">link3</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```